# Is overloading of the == operator necessary here?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, equals

I think that the overloading in code below of the == is unnecessary in the manner shown since == already compares references if not overloaded. Please advise me on the manner. It should rather be done with the one parameter Equals and the null comparison included separately?

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object param)
    {
    // If the cast is invalid, the result will be null
    Student student = param as Student;

    // Check if we have valid not null Student object
    if (student == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Compare the reference type member fields
    if (!Object.Equals(this.Name, student.Name))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Compare the value type member fields
    if (this.Age != student.Age)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Student student1, Student student2)
    {
        return Student.Equals(student1, student2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Student student1, Student student2)
    {
        return !(Student.Equals(student1, student2));
    }

  ...

  }
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Is this c#....? There are many languages on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that the overloading in code below of the == is unnecessary in the manner shown since == already compares references if not overloaded.

Yes, but the point is that *because* the operator has overloaded, you can compare for value equality rather than reference identity. For example:

```
Student x = new Student { Name = "Jon", Age = 37 };
Student y = new Student { Name = "Jon", Age = 37 };

Console.WriteLine(x == y); // Prints True
```

Without the operator overloading, the above code would print `False`, because the values of `x` and `y` refer to different objects.

That's sometimes more convenient than explicitly calling the `Equals` method.

So while it's not strictly *necessary* to overload `==` here (as the same results can be achieved in other ways), it *does* affect the behaviour. It's not a good idea to overload `==` for all types by any means, but it can make things a lot simpler for some types. I'm very glad that `string` overloads `==`, for example. A discussion about when it is a good idea to overload `==` is out of scope for this answer, fortunately - it's a matter of some debate, for starters. I do it relatively rarely for classes, but almost always for value types. (It's pretty rare to write a custom value type to start with.) The general grey area is immutable reference types...

Be aware that the overload is *only* applied when the operands are of the right compile-time type though. For example:

```
Student x = new Student { Name = "Jon", Age = 37 };
object y = new Student { Name = "Jon", Age = 37 };

Console.WriteLine(x == y); // Prints False
```

Here the overload *isn't* used because the compile-time type of `y` is `object`, not `Student`.

As a different matter, the fact that this is a *mutable* class which overrides `Equals` and therefore presumably `GetHashCode` is a matter of some concern. It's generally a bad idea to override `Equals` in classes where instances can change in a way that affects equality. It doesn't play well with collections which use equality and hashing. For example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Student, string>();
var student = new Student { Name = "Jon", Age = 37 };
dictionary[student] = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(dictionary.ContainsKey(student)); // True
dictionary.Name = "Bob";
Console.WriteLine(dictionary.ContainsKey(student)); // False
Console.WriteLine(dictionary.Keys.First() == student); // True!
```

Because the name has changed, the hash code has changed (I'm assuming a fairly simple hash code implementation which uses name and age). That means the normal hash check will fail, even though the reference is still in the dictionary.

It's okay if you don't mutate the key *after* you've added it to the dictionary, but it makes such types a bit more accident-prone, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary and counterproductive. In C#, `==` applied to objects of class type is meant to check for identity, not value equality. Overloading `==` to mean `equals` is confusing and non-idiomatic, and may cause problems with some container types.

Comment: Yes. I mean it's not like `string` overloads `==`, for example. No wait, it does...

Comment: Mostly to normalize the treatment of interned and non-interned strings. One could argue that immutable datatypes should overload `==`, but even that's a slippery slope.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your "mostly to normalize" claim? I've never seen that given as the reason before. As a counter-example, I see *lots* of questions on Stack Overflow from Java developers who mistakenly use `==` to compare strings. I'm very glad we don't get those questions for C#, simply because `==` is overloaded. That would be the case even if string interning never happened.

Comment: I do agree that immutable reference types are the ones most worthy of overloading == though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: IMHO, a lot of confusion in Java and (especially) C# would have been avoided if using `==` on types which didn't expressly support it was an error, and reference equality testing required the use of some other, non-overloadable operator.  Otherwise, with regard to Sneftel's claim, how many class types other than `String` overloaded `==` in .NET 1.0?

Comment: @supercat: I can see that "different types of equality" working well. But just because there were very few types which overloaded `==` in .NET 1.0 doesn't back up his claim that "`==` applied to objects of class type is meant to check for identity, not value equality" - if that were true, you wouldn't be able to overload `==` for classes at all, would you? (Why would the language designers have given that ability if they didn't expect people to use it to implement value equality?)

Comment: @supercat: In particular, the library design guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229032(v=vs.100).aspx say: "Consider defining operator overloads in a type that should work like a primitive type.
For example, String defines operator== and operator!=." So if you're in a similar position to `String`, I'd say it's entirely reasonable to overload `==`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The .NET Framework allows all types to define overloads of the equality operator, and I believe the CLS spec requires languages to allow the use of those overloads, so C# had to provide an overloadable equality operator that would test strings for value equality.  I don't think the Framework designers intended that classes overload the overloadable equality operator to test reference equality, and can't think of any classes that do that.  That the C# language uses the same token for reference equality as for overloadable equality means that many programmers will use `==`...

Comment: @supercat: That's just changing "C#" to ".NET" - the point is that you're *designed* to be able to overload `==`, and if you weren't intended to ever do so, I don't think it would be allowed. It's not like the CLS and C# were designed in total isolation. I didn't suggest that you would overload `==` to provide reference equality - I suggested that overloading it to provide *value equality* is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: ...when they want reference equality, in the expectation that the class of the things being compared won't have overloaded it.  If VB.NET were the dominant language rather than C#, overloading the equality operator would be much less risky, since the expression `(X = Y)` cannot request anything other than the overloadable equality operator; testing reference equality requires the expression `(X Is Y)`.  If a type overrides the equality operator, any VB.NET code which was intending to test reference equality will still do so.

Comment: The .NET Framework designers clearly intended to have languages include an overloadable equality operator.  That does not mean that the Framework designers intended for languages to allow overloading of an operator which would, absent an overload, test reference equality.  If an earlier version of a class does not overload the equality operator, changing it to do so will not break clients written in VB.NET, but will break many clients written in C#.  To my mind, that would be an argument against making such a change if clients may be written in C#.